# How to test login process?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-authentication, django-testing

I am developing a web application using Django 1.6 where I require users to log in using my login form. I want to write a test case that tests the procedure of a user logging in.

I did succeed to get a working login page, meaning I was able to log in. The following steps explain my setup. Writing a test case for this procedure did however fail. At this point I'm neither able to spot an error in my test, nor sure whether this approach makes sense before all. Can someone help me?

**Update:** In the meantime I have noticed, that my form error message was too unspecific. The issue appears to be caused by empty form fields that fail some form validation step. When I add the errors `{{ form.errors }}` to the template, the response contains the following (formatted a little less nicely):

```
<ul class="errorlist">
  <li>username
    <ul class="errorlist">
      <li>This field is required.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>password
    <ul class="errorlist">
      <li>This field is required.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm still not sure how to test this procedure most reasonably. I'm quite new to Django and the philosophy of it's testing framework. May it be, that this issue falls not directly into the scope of the Django testing framework, where models, and views, and forms are (seemingly) intended to be tested rather seperated from each other? Does this test rather fall into the realm of an independent test suite doing black-box/functional testing, e.g., using Selenium?

---

I started like this:

1. Started a fresh project, like this:

   ```
   django-admin.py startproject login_test
   ```
2. added an entry to the `login_test/urls.py`, like this:

   ```
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   )
   ```
3. made up a template at `/home/moooeeeep/login_test/templates/registration/login.html`, like this:

   ```
   {% if form.errors %}
   <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
   {% endif %}
   {% if not user.is_active %}
   <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <button type="submit">Login</button>
     <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}" />
   </form>
   {% else %}
   <p>You are logged in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.</p>
   {% endif %}
   ```
4. added the template directory to the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in the `login_test/settings.py`, like this:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
       '/home/moooeeeep/login_test/templates/',
   )
   ```
5. Sync'ed the database to get the auth-related tables, and added a superuser like this:

   ```
   python manage.py syncdb
   ```

If I did not miss a step, at this point I am able to log into my site. When logged in I get displayed my username, if not I see the form, if login fails it displays an error message in addition.

---

My test case however, after submitting correct post data, gets to see the failed login response, with the user not being logged in.

Here's my `login_test/tests.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import SESSION_KEY
from django.test import TestCase

class LogInTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = {
            'username': 'testuser',
            'password': 'secret'}
        User.objects.create_user(**self.credentials)
    def test_login(self):
        # login
        response = self.client.post('/login/', **self.credentials)      
        # should be logged in now, fails however
        self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_active)
```

Here's the output:

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_login (login_test.tests.LogInTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moooeeeep/login_test/login_test/tests.py", line 16, in test_login
    self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_active)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.008s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

---

Here's my `login_test/settings.py`:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+6e-6t8dnl$75fx%=7y$+4ipo&i=kvw(p*963p37)7o$1-)30u'
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'login_test.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'login_test.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/moooeeeep/login_test/templates/',
)
```

Comment: Could you check what is in the `response.context['user']`?

Comment: @alecxe It's the [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser).

Comment: Ok, please show your settings, especially I'm concerned about `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting.

Comment: @alecxe Please see my edit. Apparantly this is a form validation issue. The error message complains about empty form fields.

Comment: I'm not sure why do you think the form is a culprit, `login` view is called during the test. Could you show your settings (please also include your middlewares)?. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I've added my `settings.py`. It's largely the default generated configuration. I cut out some parts for the sake of legibility. The behavior is reproducible with the posted version.

Comment: `self.client.post` will issue an HTTP POST request straightaway. For the form to *possibly* be an issue, the client would have to issue a GET first. You should dump `response.status_code` and `response.content` to the screen to see what the values are.

Comment: @Louis You are right, the form is not the real issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found out that my passing of the post parameters was wrong (the dictionary must not be unpacked). I also needed to learn, that I needed to follow the redirect issued by the post request after sending the data. Then my login test worked (although the page that was target of the redirection does not exist yet).

Here's my updated test case:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase

class LogInTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = {
            'username': 'testuser',
            'password': 'secret'}
        User.objects.create_user(**self.credentials)
    def test_login(self):
        # send login data
        response = self.client.post('/login/', self.credentials, follow=True)
        # should be logged in now
        self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_active)
```

Here's the output:

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.196s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 19):

You don't want to be checking "is_active" boolean, you want to be checking

```
response.context['user'].is_authenticated
```

see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

and:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: Won't help since there is an `AnonymousUser` in the `request.context`.

Comment: it won't help in this instance, but once you have solved the AnonymouseUser issue (i.e. the user not being logged in) then you will still need to check is_authenticated instead of is_active

Comment: you could try using self.client.login(username="", password="") just to make sure that the user is able to login.

Comment: both links are not found!

Comment: @Mahdimehrabi I am not surprised those links are not found, this answer is 7 years old and for a very old version of Django

Comment: @Mahdimehrabi its a 7 year old answer..... I am not in the habit of keeping ancient answers up to date, it would become a full time job.  Also, your reply is quite rude, that will get you no help from me